# Can i write firebase real time database triggers in other files instead of index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to split large index.js file into multiple files. To organize the code can i write firebase triggers in multiple js files? If so please help me with how to write properly

## child.js

```
exports.testFunction = functions.database.ref(`/test/`).onWrite((snap, context) => {
  console.log(snap.val());
  return null;
});
```

...

## index.js

```
const childFunction = require('./child.js');
```

...

Comment: You can use as many different files as you want.  Please edit the question to show what specifically isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do is separate your functions in different files and import them in your index.js like:

> 1.) In the .js file to be imported such as ‘modA.js’
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   func1: function () {
>     // function 1
>   },
>   func2: function () {
>     // function 2
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> 2.) Import it in your index.js:
>
> ```
> var moduleA = require('./modA');
> ```
>
> 3.) Run it like:
>
> ```
> moduleA.func1();
> ```